# Differentiation of function to the power x

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given the function $f(x)=(2 + ln(x))^{x}$, find $f'(1$).

This is what I tried:

$$f(x)=(2 + \ln(x))^{x}=e^{2x+x\ln(x)}$$

So the derivative would be:

$$f'(x)=(2x + x\ln(x))'e^{2x+x\ln(x)}=(\ln(x)+3)(2+\ln(x))^{x}$$

However, I'm quite sure I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

we have $$f(x)=(2+\ln(x))^x=e^{x\ln(2+\ln(x))}$$ and the first derivative is given by
$$f'(x)=e^{x\ln(2+\ln(x))}\left(\ln(2+\ln(x))+\frac{x}{2+\ln(x)}\cdot \frac{1}{x}\right)$$ this can be simplified to 
$$f'(x)= \left( 2+\ln  \left( x \right)  \right) ^{x} \left( \ln  \left( 2+
\ln  \left( x \right)  \right) + \left( 2+\ln  \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{-1} \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrect in saying that $(2 + ln(x))^x = e^{2x + xln(x)}$.
You'll want to look into the identity $(b^x)' = b^xln(b)$. You'll just plug in your $2 + ln(x)$ for $b$ and then use the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to teaching the simple differentiation rules
$(x^a)'=ax^{a-1}$ and $(a^x)'=a^x\log a$, I often encouraged students to learn the more general rule

$$\boxed{\left(f^g\right)' = gf^{g-1}\cdot f' + f^g\log f \cdot g'}$$

Note that the two terms on the right side amount to the simpler rules, along with the chain rule. So if you take $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=a$, you recover the first simple rule (because $g'$ vanishes), and taking $f(x)=a$ and $g(x)=x$ yields the second simple rule (because $f'$ vanishes). So this rule is a generalization of both of the two simpler rules.

So for the function $h(x) = (2+\log x)^x$, use $f(x) = 2+\log x$ and $g(x) = x$ to get
$$((2+\log x)^x)' = x(2+\log x)^{x-1}\cdot\left(\frac1x\right) + (2 + \log x)^x\log(2+\log x)\cdot1
$$
which simplifies to
$$((2+\log x)^x)' = (2+\log x)^{x-1} + (2 + \log x)^x\log(2+\log x)
$$
$$ = \boxed{(2+\log x)^x\left(\dfrac{1}{2+\log x} + \log(2 + \log x)\right)}
$$

Comment: I do think writing out the general rule is a nice exercise, but I'm quite skeptical that it's a good idea for students to _learn_ it, if you mean that in the sense of _with a view toward remembering it_ instead of _with a view toward remembering how to derive it_.

Comment: @aes: The beauty of it is that if you have learned the simpler rules, you really already know it. I wouldn't replace the simpler rules with it, but I have definitely spent a class period working with it, and have announced that its derivation would appear as a bonus question on a test. My recollection is that I did this after covering logarithmic differentiation, since that's the easiest way to prove it.

Comment: That sounds reasonable; I was just worried that it sounded like you were suggesting students memorize the formula. Realizing you already know how to do this because of the chain rule is the key point.

Comment: @aes: In fact, I do advocate memorizing it--but not necessarily for elementary students that are barely able to comprehend the simpler rules. Once one grasps the impact of the rule, it won't be easily forgotten. It is a beautiful and elegant generalization that can either be ignored or appreciated as suits.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way of doing this would be:

$$f(x) = (2+\ln(x))^{x} \implies \ln(f(x))=x\ln(2+\ln(x))$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln(f(x))=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\ln(2+\ln(x))+\frac{x}{2+\ln(x)}\cdot\frac{1}{x}$$

Thus we have:

$$f'(x)=f(x)\left[\ln(2+\ln(x))+\frac{1}{2+\ln(x)}\right]=x\ln(2+\ln(x))\left[\ln(2+\ln(x))+\frac{1}{2+\ln(x)}\right]$$